# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}$

How do I calculate this limit? I can't use L'Hospital's rule here and dividing by $x^2$ doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect some of OP's confusion may come from the fact that $x$ appears in both the numerator and denominator, so I propose this solution:

Express it as $\left( \frac{x}{x-1} \right )^2$. Notice that we can simplify this to $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} \right)^2$. Inside the brackets, it approaches $- \infty$ from the left and $+\infty$ from the right, but when squared both sides of the limit approaches $+\infty$.

Answer (score 5):

The numerator tends to $1$ and the positive denominator to $0$ so the limit is $+\infty$.